# Annotations in Java

Tags: java, comments

I was wondering what exactly anotations are used for in Java, I have a basic understanding of it. However my true question is, what does annotions mean when their in a comment? For example: `/** @param **/`. Does it have any effect in the code itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Try looking here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html

Comment: That's a javadoc tag, not an annotation. That specific tag tells us details about one of the method's parameters. It does not affect your program

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering what exactly anotations are used for in Java

They are used for all sorts of things.  It is not possible to give an "exact" answer, because the use-cases for annotations are (literally) infinite.  And besides, you have probably seen a few use-cases already.  (Google for examples, if you want to find more ...)

> However my true question is, what does annotions mean when their in a comment?

When they are in comments, they are not annotations.  In this case, they are javadoc tags ... which are used when generating the javadoc *documentation* for the code,

> For example: /** @param **/. Does it have any effect in the code itself?

It has no effect on the code itself.  A Java compiler ignores anything in Java comments.  (Of course, it is *possible* to write a compiler for a Java-derived language that pays attention stuff in comments.  But that ain't Java.)

Answer (score 0):

It is used when the JavaDoc is created for a specific class, because its in a comment block the compiler doesn't look at it, and it isn't used.